# how to compute annual sum and monthly mean from raster brick

Tags: r

I have a raster brick spanning multiple years with each layer representing one day.

```
    class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 64, 68, 4352, 16071  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent     : 8.985, 11.075, 51.325, 53.195  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory 
names      :  X1971.01.01,  X1971.01.02,  X1971.01.03,  X1971.01.04,  X1971.01.05,  X1971.01.06,  X1971.01.07,  X1971.01.08,  X1971.01.09,  X1971.01.10,  X1971.01.11,  X1971.01.12,  X1971.01.13,  X1971.01.14,  X1971.01.15, ... 
min values :            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0,            0, ... 
max values : 2.155888e+00, 7.051266e+00, 2.868886e+01, 3.206402e+00, 2.514494e+01, 1.577628e+01, 1.423195e+01, 6.638916e+00, 1.299009e+01, 9.624189e+00, 1.282561e+01, 3.599981e+00, 3.951384e+00, 2.963538e+00, 1.932279e+01, ...
```

I want to create monthly raster stack by taking monthly sum of each individual year and then mean of that value.

```
indices <- format(as.Date(layer_name, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), format = "%m")
C<-stackApply(brk, indices, mean)
```

gives total mean which I can multiply by day number however issues come up with leap years.

any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `terra` instead of `raster` because according to the
authors of both packages 'it can do more, its faster and easier to use'.
I'll also make a minimal example and use `lubridate` for dealing with
dates.

```r
library('terra')
library('lubridate')

r = rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10)
values(r) = 1:ncell(r)
s = c(r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r)
s = s * 1:8
names(s) = c(
  '2020-01-01',
  '2020-01-02',
  '2020-02-01',
  '2020-02-02',
  '2021-01-01',
  '2021-01-02',
  '2021-02-01',
  '2021-02-02'
)
s
```

```
    class       : SpatRaster 
    dimensions  : 10, 10, 8  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
    resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
    extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
    source      : memory 
    names       : 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, 2020-02-01, 2020-02-02, 2021-01-01, 2021-01-02, ... 
    min values  :          1,          2,          3,          4,          5,          6, ... 
    max values  :        100,        200,        300,        400,        500,        600, ...
```

So `s` has one layer for each of two days in each of two months in each
of two years. Now we can use `terra::tapp()` to compute the aggregated
stacks, one at a time. This example will write to memory but for a real
case It would be better to consider using the `filename` argument to
write these results to disk instead.

```r
# monthly stack (sum of daily values)
# make a monthly index first
dts = names(s) |> lubridate::ymd()
monthly_i = paste(
  lubridate::year(dts),
  lubridate::month(dts),
  sep = '-') |> factor()

# aggregate the stack
monthly_s = terra::tapp(s, index = monthly_i, fun = sum)
monthly_s
```

```
    class       : SpatRaster 
    dimensions  : 10, 10, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
    resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
    extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
    source      : memory 
    names       : X2020.1, X2020.2, X2021.1, X2021.2 
    min values  :       3,       7,      11,      15 
    max values  :     300,     700,    1100,    1500
```

Now we have one layer per month, consisting in the sum of every day and
avoiding calendar issues (leap years) thanks to `lubridate`. We can do
the same for the yearly aggregates:

```r
# yearly stack (mean of every month)
# this time we have to deal with the names generated by `terra`
dts = names(monthly_s) |> gsub('X', '', x = _) |> lubridate::ym()
yearly_i = lubridate::year(dts) |> factor()

# aggregate the stack
yearly_s = terra::tapp(monthly_s, index = yearly_i, fun = mean)
yearly_s
```

```
    class       : SpatRaster 
    dimensions  : 10, 10, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
    resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
    extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
    source      : memory 
    names       : X2020, X2021 
    min values  :     5,    13 
    max values  :   500,  1300
```

Note that the initial stack here had pretty names, this code should be
adapted to deal with the generated ones as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, nlyr=8, vals=1:ncell(r))
r <- r * 1:8
time(r) <- as.Date(c('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02',  '2021-02-01', '2021-02-02'))
```

To get the sum for each year/month, and then avereage these to get the monthly mean across years you can do.

```
ym <- tapp(s, "yearmonths", sum)
m <- tapp(ym, "months", mean)

m
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source(s)   : memory
names       : m_1,  m_2 
min values  :   7,   11 
max values  : 700, 1100 
time (mnts) : Jan to Feb 

time(m, "months")
#[1] 1 2
```

Coy's solution works fine (although he interpreted the question differently) but is unnecessarily complex as the date manipulation is already built in. You can get his result with:

```
y <- tapp(ym, "years", mean)
y
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : y_2020, y_2021 
#min values  :      5,     13 
#max values  :    500,   1300 
#time (years): 2020 to 2021
```

If you read your (netCDF) file with `rast(filename.nc)` you probably get the time stamps set automatically, so that you do not have to set them as I do in the example data. Otherwise, you can extract them from the layer names like this:

```
#nms <- names(x)
nms <- c("X1971.01.01",  "X1971.01.02")
as.Date(nms, "X%Y.%m.%d")
#[1] "1971-01-01" "1971-01-02"
```